# .htaccess GET Rewrite issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been stuck on this for days now and have tried multiple configurations with my .htaccess file but I am at my end. This is what I have so far.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule   ^product/([a-z]+)$  /product.php?product_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It properly Rewrites the url for PHP extensions and also appends a trailing slash to any of my urls. My problem is with the last line.  I would like all url requests to the product such as mywebsite.com/product/1234 to be passed to my script like mywebsite.com/product.php?product_id=1234.

When I go to mywebsite.com/product/1234/  I get a "404 Not Found" with the error "The requested URL /base_dir/1234.php was not found on this server."

I am on shared hosting with Go Daddy.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you go to: `http://mywebsite.com/product/1234/`, your second last `RewriteRule` gets kicked in (note that `[L]` specifies that no more rewriting will take place after this redirect):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

which, should redirect you to: `http://mywebsite.com/product/1234.php`

I am not too familiar with .htaccess rules, but you should interchange the position of your last and second last lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^product/([a-z]+)$  /product.php?product_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Stoic, but unfortunately when I try that I receive the error "This page has a redirect loop".